# Is it possible that a set be measurable with a measure function but not with the other?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider we have a measurable subset $A$ of euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^p$ with respect to Lebesgue measure. Is it always measurable in respect to any measure function (I mean non-negative,finite,regular and additive measures here) or there is situation which it may or may not measurable depending on measure function? Under which measure function conditions, an specified set is always measurable?

Comment: Measurability of a set does not follow from what measure is being considered, but rather what sigma algebra you consider. The sigma algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets is not a collection of measurable sets only for the Lebesgue measure in particular.

Comment: You may be interested in another closely related question: can any premeasure defined on semi-open intervals be extended to a measure on Lebesgue sigma algebra.

Comment: I am not sure If I have chosen the right words in my question. But I am reading Rudin Book and it started from an additive set function for elementary sets (a ring) and then he generated a sigma-ring (include some subsets of R^p) based on that set function which named it Mue-Measurable sets. For example I know that Borel sets always belong to that family of sets, Does it true for other subset of R^p too?

Comment: @MehdiMowlavi, I haven't checked the book you referenced, but I guess that you are talking about completion. Lebesgue measure theory usually works like this: you _define_ some premeasure on some simple family of subsets of $X$, next extend it to the algebra generated by this family, next you extend it to an _outer_ measure on $2^X$ — this object will not be countably additive, and then restrict it to the largest family of sets on which it is countably additive. This procedure is called Caratheodory extension.

Comment: Thank you @tsnao. I see, so first a sigma-ring as a family of subset of X (R^p or any other set) is defined as measurable sets and then a non-negative countable additive measure is define for every measurable set (if it is required). So we only can use sigma-ring properties to determine a set belong to measurable sets or not! Another thing, I thought that algebra used for function set and closeness of it regard to summation and product of two functions and ring used in case of set operation. Is there any standard for them?!